# Get array size for GROUP_CONCAT() - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I am running a query where I used `GROUP_CONCAT()` and now I want to know the length of this array. I used `LENGTH()`, however, this shows the number of characters in the row. Should I even use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the first place?

The results I am expecting:

| Id | GROUP_CONACT() | LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B | 2 |
| 2 | C, D | 2 |
| 3 | E, F, G | 3 |
| 4 | A, D | 2 |
| 5 | A, B, D, E, G | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is counting the number of occurrence of ','+1:
Use

```
ROUND (   
        (
          LENGTH(concated)-LENGTH(REPLACE(concated, ",", "")))/LENGTH(",")+1
    ) AS COUNT
```

Replace concated to your GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't just use the `COUNT()` function, e.g.:

```
item | accessory
1    | a
1    | b
1    | c
2    | d
2    | e
```

```sql
SELECT item,
       GROUP_CONCAT(accessory) AS accessories,  -- the CSV string
       COUNT(*) AS num_accessories              -- the "size" of the array
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY item;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim! I am looking for something different - I have updated the post!

Comment: My answer works just fine for your requirement, and the answer you accepted is not optimal.